# Price of each order shown as order price

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Write a SQL query that shows the price of each order made by customers
whose last name starts with the letter M. Display the order number, the
last name on the order, and the price of the order (Order Price). Show the results with the highest order price first. Use single quotes to provide the aggregate alias.

Produces a result making sure it answers the question fully

```
Select `CustomerLastName`,petshop_order.OrderNo, 
sum(item.ItemPrice) as `Order Price`
from customer,petshop_order,petshop_order_item,item
where `CustomerLastName` like "M%"
 And (customer.ssn=petshop_order.ssn
 And petshop_order.OrderNo = petshop_order_item.OrderNo
 And petshop_order_item.SKU=item.SKU)
Group by `OrderNo`
Order By `Order Price` DESC;
```

I understand that this may be poor syntax....This is very my first Database Class. Unfortunately, this how the Professor taught it to us.

Comment: Hey, no worries about the syntax.  There are better ways but you gotta learn somewhere.  What's the problem with what you currently have?  Also, is that MySQL?

Comment: Thanks! And yes this is MySQL and workbench. and i was just trying to make sure im not missing anything and it answers the question appropriately.

Comment: You'll find the best luck with that over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ , StackOverflow is for troubleshooting specific questions or problems and it may lead to your post getting closed here.  That said your query looks like it will work to me and I'll post some feedback into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall, your query logic looks correct.  Here is some general feedback and tips:

**Implicit vs Explicit Joins**

Comma separated tables with correlated `WHERE` clauses are called implicit joins:

```
from customer,petshop_order,petshop_order_item,item
where (customer.ssn=petshop_order.ssn
 And petshop_order.OrderNo = petshop_order_item.OrderNo
 And petshop_order_item.SKU=item.SKU)
```

Explicit joins are very widely preferred, they use the `JOIN` keyword and have the correlating clause directly in a join predicate:

```
FROM customer
JOIN petshop_order ON customer.ssn=petshop_order.ssn
JOIN petshop_order_item ON petshop_order.OrderNo = petshop_order_item.OrderNo
JOIN item ON petshop_order_item.SKU = item.SKU
```

They are generally easier to read, and when you get into different join types it is much, much easier to track them when they are expressed explicitly, `LEFT JOIN`, over implicitly, `*=` or `(+)`.

**Aliases**

Aliases are your friend and make everything more readable.  For instance add table aliases to the above `JOIN` and you can see the difference in readability:

```
FROM customer as c
JOIN petshop_order as po ON c.ssn = po.ssn
JOIN petshop_order_item as poi ON po.OrderNo = poi.OrderNo
JOIN item as i ON poi.SKU = i.SKU
```

Once we alias `customer` as `c` we can refer to it as `c` everywhere else, etc.

**Special DBMS Rules**

Most database management systems force you to include all non-aggregate fields in your `GROUP BY` if you include an aggregate.  For your query, this would mean that `CustomerLastName` would also need to be in the grouping.

Concised down a bit:

```
SELECT CustomerLastName, OrderNo, SUM(ItemPrice)
FROM ..
WHERE ..
GROUP BY CustomerLastName, OrderNo
```

MySQL does not enforce this, so your current query looks like it should work, but it's worth noting that each DBMS product incorporates their own variety of rules and syntaxes that others may not.